# Why Tab bar is going to hide when Push to another View in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using `TabBarController` with four tabs in my applicatin. In the second Tab I'm using `PageViewcontroller`. `PageViewController` contains Five pages. Where the first Page view contains the button. On button click we can navigate to another view.  When we navigate to another view,  the tab is going to hide.

But I don't want to hide the Tab bar.

Anyone can please help to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to make `UITabBar` visible in all the screens of your app you need to take `UINavigationController` for all the tabs, `UINavigationController` will be the viewControllers with relational segue and `UINavigationController`'s root view controllers will be your initial controllers which you want to show on Tabs

Below is the screenshot of how you design it using your storyboard

[image]

And here is how it works

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deselect Hide bottom bar on push as below :

[image]

Or programatically :

```
yourViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

Comment: its already unchecked .but still tab bar is not showing.. any other solution please.

Comment: where should i write this line in code.. should i write this  from where we are navigating.

Comment: while you push controller .

Comment: which navigation controller use for this controller . for example it has separate NaviagtionController or use TabViewController's NavigationController.